# c#- Display error message if there is no issue permission

Tags: c#

I have a program in c# that allow users to issue events ( think of it like different vouchers from different category). In the program, there is a function called promotion permission to set access to the event. The two access are view permission and issue permission. View permission allow user to view the event and issue permission allow user to issue (print) out the event. For example, if the event is set to as view permission: yes and issue permission : no , then user cannot issue the event but could view it. If both cases are yes then user may issue the event.

Now I have another function in program to issue the event(voucher). In that program, it shows a list of events (when user enter their id) and are able to tick(checkbox) the event they wish to issue. What I need is if the event does not have issue permission but view permission, it should not allowed user to tick the checkbox and if they try to do so, it should throw a error message informing user of the restriction.

This is my code:

```
   private void lisVieBenefits_ItemChecked(object sender, ItemCheckedEventArgs e)
    {
        RestartAutoLogoffTimer();
        DataSet dsData = oBSPromoPermission.GetBrowseData();

    if (e.Item.Checked && !IsEnoughtToRedeemPointEarnReward())
        {
            // Uncheck previous item
            e.Item.Checked = false;
            return;
        }

        if (panBenefitSelection.Enabled)
        {
            int intTotal = 0;
            for (int intCounter = 0; intCounter < lisVieBenefits.Items.Count; intCounter++)
            {
                if (lisVieBenefits.Items[0].ListView.Items[intCounter].Checked)
                    intTotal += 1;
            }

            if (intTotal > intMaxBenefitSelection)
            {
                lisVieBenefits.Items[0].ListView.Items[e.Item.Index].Checked = false;
                SetErrorHint("Please select not more than (" + intMaxBenefitSelection + ") benefit selection");
            }



            if (dsData.Tables[0].Columns[3].ToString() == "True" && dsData.Tables[0].Columns[4].ToString() == "False")
            {

                //  lisVieBenefits.Items[0].ListView.Items[e.Item.Index].Checked = false;
                SetErrorHint("This event does not have an issue permission");
            }


        }
```

I declared and call the class:
 `private BSPromoPermission oBSPromoPermission = new BSPromoPermission();`

So,`dsData` is a dataset variable declared to call the database that have view permission and issue permission. As shown in the code, column[3] is set to true for view permission and column[4] is set to false for issue permission. 
Somehow this isn't working. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: why not make seperate lists for view and issue permission and when user check the checkbox then verify if the specific item is avaliable in your issue list

Comment: @zackraiyan I know the last statement is what makes the magic happens. The dataset does return values matching promotion permission columns but it doesn't work

Comment: are u sure u can read from the dataset ?

Comment: @Agent_Orange Because both constraints must be met to display the message. If view is yes and issue is no then it should throw the message, thats why it's better to merge them

Comment: @zackraiyan Well i did debug and the dataset did return values matching promotion permission so that's a yes?

Comment: if that is the case just try using a nested if or just use `And` in the last if statement :)

Comment: I spent many days on this problem, not sure what i did wrong.

Comment: what do you mean AND?

Comment: @zackraiyan Can you invite me to discussion, so we don't have to keep the comment section long

Comment: i am writing an answer,please make sure to comment before u downvote it

Comment: @zackraiyan I don't downvote people even if the answer is incorrect. Don't worry

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/166859/discussion-between-lord-jesus-and-zack-raiyan).

Comment: Are you there???